# Problem related to min $\ ||Ax-b||^2$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Consider the following problem: $$minimize\ ||Ax-b||^2,$$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $b$ is a vector of dimension $m$.
>
> What would be a necessary condition of optimality?

First off I don't understand how is possible to minimize this $\ ||Ax-b||^2,$ I haven't seen problems stated like that, the usual style is min $f(x)\ s.t. ax<b, cx+e<d,$ etc.

Could someone light me up please? What should I do in this cases?

Comment: Check the stationarity condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

with the usual norm you  have a function
$$
||Ax-b||^2=\sum_{j=1}^m \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ji}x_i\right)-b_j  \right]^2=f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)
$$

do you know how to minimize a function of $n$ variables?

Comment: no, I don't the most have been 2 variables :)

Comment: It is essentially th same, but now we have $n$ partial derivative that are $=0$ ate the stationary points,  and the Hessian is a $n \times n$ matrix, whose eigenvalues determine the nature of the stationary points. You cansearch on the web where there are many post ( eg: https://profs.info.uaic.ro/~fliacob/An1/2014-2015/Resurse%20auxiliare/11_Aplicatii%20ale%20diferentiabilitatii%20functiilor%20reale/Chris%20Good_Extreme%20Values%20of%20Functions%20of%20Several%20Variables.pdf

Comment: oh ok I'll check it.